# iPhone Tableview Use Cells in Horizontal Scrolling not Vertical

Tags: iphone, rotation, uitableview

This is not an uiview orientation question, I want to Have the iphone in Portrait or Landscape, and I want a standard tableview(controller?) that will display cells in a vertical strip down the iphone and the tableview scrolls horizontally.
-I.e. a 100% normal tableview, that is rotated 90deg without rotating the phone orientation

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in the view controller rotate the tableView in viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {   
 self.table.rowHeight = 320.0;   
 self.table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;   
 // Rotates the view.   
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707963);    
 self.table.transform = transform;  
 // Repositions and resizes the view.   
 CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 90, 320, 300);  
 self.table.frame = contentRect;    
 self.table.pagingEnabled
        = YES;   
 [super viewDidLoad]; 
}
```

but you will have cell rotated 90°!!! I solved rotating cellView -90°

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.5707963);
        cell.transform = transform;
}
```

Comment: Hi nikoz, do you know to solve a problem with blurred content inside the cells when rotate the UITableView like this?

Comment: Would probably be better to use the 'M_PI_2' constant, instead of 1.5707963.  Easier to read, easier on the eyes, and less prone to typos.

eg: `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);`

Answer (score 0):

Now anybody looking for simple and better way use UICollectionView with **"Horizontal scrolling"** enabled.