# IOS - How to create TableView with horizontal scrollable lists

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, layout

I'm trying to implement a table view with scrollable horizontal items (with unknown number of items) like the illustration below:

[image]

The UI should behave like so:

1. At the init state the table cell shows a label and some text and the circle item pops out of the right side
2. If the users swipes from right to left, the label and text fades out and the horizontal list (inside the cell) takes it's place

---

I thought about using TableView and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and creating a prototype cell, but then I need to remember the list horizontal position and init the cell properly on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and that will probably affect performance.

**Q:** What layout would you use in order to achieve this goal, any input / tutorial would be appreciated

Comment: You should use `UITableView`, with reusable cells, and with a `UIScrollView` as the sideways scroller. You can store the values of horizontal position and retrieve them when the cell is init'd in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Retrieving a value for a dictionary storing the horizontal position should be trivial in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: nicely illustrated for immediate clarity!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use a `UITableView` and add a `UICollectionView` to your reusable tableView cell. `UICollectionView` works similar to `UITableView` in that the "items" (like cells) are reusable and instantiated only when they will appear on screen. I did a quick google search for tutorials and found [UICollectionView in UITableViewCell](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/). Check that out and a few other StackOverflow questions regarding design and you should be golden.

Comment: Can anyone reference a swift example?

Comment: [Swift version](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/)

Comment: @Amir this code will work for single cell right .How to make move for all cell's horizontally

Comment: @Raviteja I guess with this code you can make it for all cell row, please look this https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell

Answer (score 6):

Using `UIScrollView` may require heavy effort if there are large amount of UI elements inside each scrollview because you have to instantiate all those upfront. A better solution is to define your custom `UITableViewCell` which has its own `UITableView` but rotated in 90 degree for horizontal scrolling. UI elements inside will be created only when they need to be shown by using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Please see some sample code on how to create a 90 degree rotated table view:

[iPhone Tableview Use Cells in Horizontal Scrolling not Vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778521/iphone-tableview-use-cells-in-horizontal-scrolling-not-vertical)

Comment: Why in the world would you rotate a tableView instead of using a `UICollectionView` that's designed to scroll sideways?

Comment: Is there any hidden advantage in using rotated `UITableView` than using `UICollectionView`?

Comment: @AndrewRobinson Because collection views are complicated to size, especially when inside a table view cell. A horizontal table view would simplify things a lot if you only needed one row.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ScrollView to put inside your  tableview and set the values "Direction lock enabled" and "Paging Enabled" to true for the scrollview.

Comment: Cool I will try that, but can you elaborate a bit about those properties?

Comment: If using UIScrollView, what are the limitations regarding the number of items in each row?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz, `UIScrollView` also uses a prototype / reusable cell pattern. There wouldn't be # of items in a row limitations, unless enforced by you. [UIScrollView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html)

Comment: @AndrewRobinson, thanks for the reply ... however I could not find the reusable cell property / function in the docs, could you please be more specific?

Comment: I wish I wasn't on my phone when I replied to this, it's definitely not a `UIScrollView` that you want, it's a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 2):

### - SwiftUI

In swiftUI, you can use the power of `Stack`s and `ScrollView` alongside with `List` (if you want):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var verticalData = 0...3
    var horizontalData = 0...15

    var body: some View {
        List(self.verticalData, id: \.self) { vData in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(self.horizontalData, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I used a `List` for vertical data and a horizontal `ScrollView` containing a `HStack` (Horizonl stack) of circles.

### - Example

The following code is the the only code to reproduce a view exactly like your illustration (4 years later on iPhone Xs):

```
struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("Label")
                    Text("Some text here")
                }
                ForEach(0...15, id: \.self) { _ in
                    CircleView()
                }
            }
            .padding(16)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0...3, id: \.self) { _ in
                RowView()
            }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
    }
}
```

### - Result

[image]

Comment: Performance is not acceptable if you try this.  It's fine if you have a handful of items.  the entire point of collection views (including scroll views) is that performance is incredibly better than a static scroll of items.