# How to implement a Scrollable Horizontal List in a UITableViewCell? [iOS]

Tags: ios, uitableview

I needed to create a scrollable horizontal list of items in a UITableViewCell. They can be images or tags like those but horizontally scrollable:
[image][image]

My initial approach was to create a UIStackView inside of a UIScrollView and add items to this UIStackView. This worked fine. However the problem is; this operation take too much time and heavily lag the scrolling of UITableView.

So what is the best approach here?

Please note that there could be more than 1 horizontal lists in my UITableViewCell and scrolling to those cells blocked my UI for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Go for a collection view inside the UITableViewCell

Comment: Yes, try CollectionView https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864881/6203030

Comment: Collection view would be best approach in such cases