# How to do a tableview horizontal in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, cross-platform

I need to doy a tableview with two colums but I dont know to put in horizontal

[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwCFX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplicate of this : [IOS - How to create TabelView with horizontal scrollable lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844684/ios-how-to-create-tabelview-with-horizontal-scrollable-lists)

In short : add an UICollectionView into UITableView or use UICollectionView instead of UITableView depend on your expectation.

Case 1 : If you want something like this:

*item1-item2-item3-item4...*
 
I would recommend to use UICollectionView and set the option to display set of items horizontally

Case 2: If you want something like this:

*item1-item2-item3-item4...* 

*item1-item2-item3-item4...*

.................

 I would recommend to put UICollectionView inside UITableView. The rest will be the same as Case 1