# How to enable horizontal scroll of UICollection View that is within a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a `UICollectionView` placed inside a `UITableViewCell`. The collection view has its scroll direction set to horizontal. However, when I swipe left or right on it to try and scroll, it doesn't work. Instead the table view cell is just pressed. It seems like the table view is eating up the gesture and not allowing the collection view to register it.

How can I make it so the collection view can scroll left and right with horizontal swipes, while still allowing the parent table view to scroll vertically?

I went through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844684/ios-how-to-create-tableview-with-horizontal-scrollable-lists) and its accepted answer's [linked blog post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/), but it did not seem to address the issue I am having. On a whim, I also tried throwing `sendSubviewToBack(self.contentView)` in my table view cell's `awakeFromNib()` based on [this question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675236), but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: We need more information to try to help. Are you designing this with Prototypes in Storyboard? Or doing everything via code?

Comment: I designed it with Storyboard. Let me know if/what code you want to see? It's literally just a UITableView which the cell is designed with a UICollectionView inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to know without seeing your project...

Here, though, is about as basic of a setup as possible.

- Table view controller
- cell prototype and class with a "row label" and a collection view
- collection view prototype and class

**Source for Storyboard:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="19529" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="Ets-ss-TQd">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="19519"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Table Col Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="6jQ-dU-swf">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="Ets-ss-TQd" customClass="TableColTableViewController" customModule="MoreScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="-1" estimatedSectionHeaderHeight="-1" sectionFooterHeight="-1" estimatedSectionFooterHeight="-1" id="zYt-i6-X2h">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="someTableCell" rowHeight="125" id="B1r-57-a4y" customClass="SomeTableCell" customModule="MoreScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44.5" width="320" height="125"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="B1r-57-a4y" id="Zyt-9U-dTe">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="125"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="d9m-rN-Eyd">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="54" width="288" height="60"/>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="E26-bE-U5T"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                            <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="4" id="mrH-RV-vqe">
                                                <size key="itemSize" width="92" height="50"/>
                                                <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                                <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                                <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                                            </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                                            <cells>
                                                <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="someCollectionCell" id="JEj-s8-EVA" customClass="SomeCollectionCell" customModule="MoreScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="5" width="92" height="50"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                    <collectionViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="mgI-0a-PJH">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="92" height="50"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wJ1-UE-IvG">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="76" height="34"/>
                                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="wJ1-UE-IvG" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="mgI-0a-PJH" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="7v0-S7-Kcb"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="wJ1-UE-IvG" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="mgI-0a-PJH" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="NUW-9U-OkK"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="wJ1-UE-IvG" secondAttribute="bottom" id="YXn-Qi-b3X"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="wJ1-UE-IvG" secondAttribute="trailing" id="ZNu-px-4Va"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                    </collectionViewCellContentView>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <outlet property="label" destination="wJ1-UE-IvG" id="0fz-E6-bfF"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </collectionViewCell>
                                            </cells>
                                            <connections>
                                                <outlet property="dataSource" destination="B1r-57-a4y" id="hHd-RQ-xJb"/>
                                                <outlet property="delegate" destination="B1r-57-a4y" id="3kW-TN-RKS"/>
                                            </connections>
                                        </collectionView>
                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Row Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GpB-tj-mDa">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11" width="288" height="35"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="d9m-rN-Eyd" secondAttribute="trailing" id="3Fd-ue-yEB"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="d9m-rN-Eyd" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="999" id="5EL-HQ-hli"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="GpB-tj-mDa" secondAttribute="trailing" id="UiZ-V8-tk0"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="d9m-rN-Eyd" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Zyt-9U-dTe" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="axO-Nr-EUG"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="GpB-tj-mDa" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Zyt-9U-dTe" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="hM3-MG-T66"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="d9m-rN-Eyd" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="GpB-tj-mDa" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="muE-Zg-mgg"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="GpB-tj-mDa" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Zyt-9U-dTe" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="nea-19-Qvm"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="collectionView" destination="d9m-rN-Eyd" id="UOs-i9-xDd"/>
                                    <outlet property="rowTitleLabel" destination="GpB-tj-mDa" id="LpD-4r-JgM"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="Ets-ss-TQd" id="RC7-c1-RLO"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="Ets-ss-TQd" id="sLA-mZ-FSY"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="435-nV-YGQ" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="125.625" y="225"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

**Classes:**

```
import UIKit

struct SomeDataStruct {
    var color: UIColor = .white
    var num: Int = 0
}

class TableColTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myData: [SomeDataStruct] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue, .cyan, .magenta, .yellow,
            .red, .green, .blue, .orange, .brown, .purple,
        ]
        let nums: [Int] = [
            12, 15, 8, 21, 17, 14,
            16, 10, 5, 13, 20, 19,
        ]
        for (c, n) in zip(colors, nums) {
            let d = SomeDataStruct(color: c, num: n)
            myData.append(d)
        }
        
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "someTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SomeTableCell
        cell.rowTitleLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.thisData = myData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class SomeTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var rowTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var thisData: SomeDataStruct = SomeDataStruct() {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
extension SomeTableCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return thisData.num
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "someCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SomeCollectionCell
        cell.label.text = "Cell \(indexPath.item)"
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = thisData.color
        return cell
    }
}
class SomeCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and let you know what I find.

Comment: So I guess I found my issues thanks to your answer. I had `userActionEnabled` set to `false` for my collection view lol. I did that originally because I wasn't able to click on the parent collection view cell otherwise. Now I have to figure out how to enable that, because my child collection view is taking all the touches now...